# Problemas al cargar CSS con Node JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, nodejs

cuando cargo el localhost:8080, en la consola me tira el error

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/style/main.css'
> because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME
> type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

y no me carga el css. Alguna solucion?

Comment: Tienes que lograr que el servidor web le diga al cliente, cuando se le va a pasar la hoja de estilos, que el `Content-type` (ese es un header HTTP) es `text/css`. No es un error de programación.... por lo menos no del lado del cliente... el problema es del lado del servidor que no está pasando el Content-type apropiado.

Comment: Estas tratando de cargar esta hoja CSS desde un index.html?

Comment: Si @g.4. Estoy probando node js